# Passing Parameter Value to the Apx(server-side controller) in lightning

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-apps, aura

I am very new in Lightning App Development. I am getting an error this error(**Uncaught error in $A.run() : component is not defined**) When i want to pass the  component value to the Apex(Server-Side Controller) in lightning using JS(Client-Side Controller).

Here is my Code for my Code

COMPONENT
[image]

CLIENT SIDE
[image]

SERVER SIDE CONTROLLER[image]

Comment: did u check if there are ticket, event product & event records existing for the ticket id you are passing ?

Comment: yes there is ..

Comment: It will be best if you can paste your code here instead of images, so that we can try on our machine.

Comment: ya.. sorry.. next time i will paste my code . i already solve the error. Thankyou for your will to help. i really appreciate it.

Answer (score 2):

One problem is that in your button, the press attribute shouldn't be written as a merge field.

```
<ui:button label="Go" press="c.search" />
```

You also have a misspelling in your client-side controller. It should be:

```
search : function(component, event, helper){
```

You might be getting the message "component is not defined" because the variable was named "componet"

Also, you could also simplify you server-side controller if you wanted: (unrelated to the error)

```
public class CheckinCntrlr{
    @AuraEnabled
    public static String checkfoundevent(String ticketid1){
        Ticket__c obj = [
            SELECT Event_Product__r.Event__c.Name 
            FROM Ticket__c
            WHERE Id = :ticketid1
        ];
        return obj.Event_Product__r.Event__c.Name;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thankyou for your will to help. I already solve the problem :)

Comment: @DanrylTigolCarpio Excellent. Glad I could help.